# c# - How do I find my input text is BOLD Typography?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-office

I have uploaded a ms word file on my sever. After uploading the file I am reading that file and I want read **BOLD** words only. The thing is that I can able to find whether the file contains **BOLD** words or not. But I want to read that **BOLD** words.
 thought the system says, this Paragraph contains  a bold word. but I want to read only those bold words.

I have used MS office library to read word file.
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

following is my code to detect **BOLD** words.

```
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paragraph in doc.Paragraphs)
    {
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range parRng = paragraph.Range;
     if (parRng.Bold > 0)
        {
         //  here i can able to detect this paragraph contains bold 
         //character but unable to read those specfic bold words
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through Paragraphs, use Sentences. And futher you can iterate though each word to find out the Bold text.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System;

namespace consolFindBoldWord
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application application = new Application();
            Document doc = application.Documents.Open("I:\\word.docx");

            foreach (Range s in doc.Sentences)
            {
                foreach (Range rg in s.Words)
                {
                    if (rg.Bold == -1)
                    {

                        /*  WRITE YOUR CODE HERE IF WORD IS BOLD*/
                        Console.WriteLine("Bold : {0}", rg.Text);
                    }
                }
            }

            doc.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @maaz patel If answer worked for you, upvote please :-)